# How to get aws api gateway endpoint url from command line interface

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have created an aws lambda function by following aws tutorial located here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html

Once the app is deployed using sam cli the output shows the api gateway endpoint url.
I would like to know how I can retrieve this information for a function which is already deployed using the command line interface.

Thank you

Comment: What url? A lambda does not really have a url.

Comment: The url which can be used to access the lambda function from a browser.

Comment: `https://{region}.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home#/functions/{function_name}`.

Comment: The CLI does not care about the URLs the AWS console uses / needs / works with.

Comment: can you explain what this URL would be for - "seeing" the URL in the console UI, or invoking the lambda?  There is not inherently a URL to invoke lambdas in AWS

Comment: I was working through this startup guide from aws. Once the lambda is deployed using sam cli it shows the api gateway endpoint url. I'd like to know if there is a way to get this information for a lambda which is already deployed using the same cli.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html

Comment: "api gateway endpoint url" is something **ENTIRELY** different. An Api Gateway does have a publicly reachable URL, that is basically the point of an Api Gateway, a lambda does not have that, because it is a lambda and not an Api Gateway.

Comment: Thank you I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** after clarifications in comments:

```
aws apigatewayv2 get-apis
```

**Output example**:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "ApiEndpoint": "wss://ko1uatx3.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com",
            "ApiId": "ko1uatx3",
            "ApiKeySelectionExpression": "$request.header.x-api-key",
            "CreatedDate": "2021-07-07T08:54:13Z",
            "Description": "Serverless Websockets",
            "Name": "dev-scrum-estimation-serverless-websockets",
            "ProtocolType": "WEBSOCKET",
            "RouteSelectionExpression": "$request.body.action",
            "Tags": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And how does this output any URL?

Comment: That's the internal URL. I.e ARN which Lambda functions use.

Comment: Which is not at all what OP is looking for.

Comment: if you want the gateway one, use  aws apigatewayv2 get-apis

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. A lambda does not have a URL.

An Api Gateway does have a public URL because that is the point of an Api Gateway, to make internal functions such as lambdas publicly accessible. If you want to make an existing lambda publicly accessible either incorporate it into an existing Api Gateway or set up a new gateway with the lambda as a target. To know *how* to integrate it into an Api Gateway is too much to cover in this answer, there a thousands of tutorials out there.

Comment: I'd like to know how I can retrieve the api gateway url already associated with a lambda.
I would like to do this using the aws cli.

Comment: @kav that does generally not work, a lambda does not know which api gateway it is associated with, it could be 0, 1, 2, ... a lambda is a lambda. Only when looking at lambda permissions may you be able to *infer* which api gateway *may* be referencing it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html . Only if you know which api gateway is associated with which lambda (because you just deployed it) can you output the proper endpoint url.

Comment: At the bottom of the tutorial they reference this line to access the gateway.
```curl https://<restapiid>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/```
This url is also listed as an output of the sam cli deployment.
I've already deployed function and do not have the url. Is there a way for me to get <restapiid> for something I've already deployed previously?

Comment: @kav Yes, go to the AWS console, go to the Api Gateway and check there or run `aws apigateway get-rest-apis` or `aws apigatewayv2 get-apis` depending on the API you deploy.

Comment: In this case I do not have access to management console, is there a way to do it though cli?

Comment: @kav ... or run `aws apigateway get-rest-apis` or `aws apigatewayv2 get-apis` depending on the API you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not understanding the question but for anyone coming here looking for a list of API Gateway paths, you can pull the endpoint names out of API Gateway using `aws apigateway get-resources`. Replace `abcd1234` with your API Gateway instance ID.

`aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id abcd1234`

If you need just the URL names, you can use something like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract just the `path` property:

`aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id abcd1234 | jq '.items[ ] | .path'`